# How to shuffle array without duplicate elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, shuffle

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

How to suffle this array elements  so new array contain this elements in random order without any duplicate element?

E.g: `new array = [4, 1, 3, 5, 2];`

Comment: or look at, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 1):

As a person that used jQuery as a "golden hammer" for a long time, my advise would be to use the appropiate tool for each task. In this case, I'd use the [`shuffle()`](http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle) method in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for the task.

```
var new_array=_.shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
arr = shuffle(arr);

function shuffle(arr) {
    for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
    return arr;
}
```

courtesy: http://jsfiddle.net/timur/bAynQ/